# How to deploy to azure app service from VSTS? (error)

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-pipelines

I setup build definition:
[image]

but it was break. Do you know that it can be?
[image]

Comment: Change system.debug variable value to true and queue build again, then check whether there are detail errors. On the other hand, try to deploy app to azure via Visual Studio directly (Right click project > Publish >Microsoft Azure Web app) and check the result.

Comment: I can build directly Visual Studio but VS needed a lot of additional files.

Comment: Which files it needs? You need to publish it to Azure instead of just build. You can try to create a new app service in azure, then queue build with that app service. On the other hand, are there detail errors after setting system.debug to true and queue build?

Comment: Also, try to access Https://[site].scm.azurewebsites.net/deployments/2201495844511438 and Https://[site].scm.azurewebsites.net/deployments/2201495844511438/log, then check whether there are errors in downloaded JSON files.

Comment: Regarding publish nodejs project to azure, you can create a new nodejs project in VS (Install https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/07/28/node-js-tools-1-2-visual-studio-2015/), then right click project > Publish